# Migrating existing site to Azure is slow

Tags: php, azure, wordpress

I am migrating a site to Azure. However the site is now running unacceptably slow. The setup is as follows:

- Azure standard Linux apps service plan
- MySQL on Azure standard instance

Here's some of the things I've tried:

- Increasing the size of the web VM
- Increasing the size of the database VM
- Disabling output buffering
- Enabling wordpress query caches and viewing database response times
- Disabling Azure VM affinity routing
- Disabling response buffering
- Disabling all plugins
- Testing database performance (I wrote a simple page to time the response for a simple query, this page claims to take .001-.002 seconds to render, but TTFB reported by Chrome is around 2.7 seconds).

To give you an idea of the sense of the scale of the problem the current live site loads in around 1 second, the Azure version loads in about 10 seconds.

Does anyone have any advice or suggestions as to what I should look at next?

Comment: you need to say everything the site was on before azure and what specs the VM is on now

Comment: It's on an Azure S1 Linux instance. I'm not sure of the previous specs. To be honest I don't think it's a raw spec/performance issue because CPU and RAM usage are ticking along around 10% and 60% respectively. @Mike

Comment: Are you sure the Linux VM and the MySQL instance are in the same resource group and the same Azure region?

Comment: @LexLi Yep! I put some stats in my question which show that connections to the database are as fast as expected.

Comment: Please tell me you found a solution, I appear to be having the same issue

Comment: @BlackMagic I migrated the site to a Windows VM which significantly improved the issue. It's still slower than I would expect but it's acceptable now.